# Android Studio IDE Internal error occurence when trying to run app on device: "NoClassDefFoundError com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException"

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a strange one that's occuring in Android Studio 2.3.

I have an Oppo A37S connected to the computer. I've made sure USB Debugging is enabled on it, and `adb devices` confirms that it exists as a connected device.

However, when I clicked Run 'App' (F10) in Android Studio, it doesn't list any devices connected to the computer. When I exited out of the window that was supposed to list the devices, I get an `NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException` error.

Going to `Run -> Edit Configurations` and changing the target to `USB devices` doesn't build the project and instead just returns that error.

And I don't even use JSch!

What am I missing?

EDIT: Restarting the ADB server doesn't work either.

EDIT 2: The stacktrace of said error - it also refers to Firebase Testing:

```
com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
    at com.google.gct.testing.android.CloudDeviceNameRenderer.isApplicable(CloudDeviceNameRenderer.java:31)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.ConnectedAndroidDevice.getRendererExtension(ConnectedAndroidDevice.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.ConnectedAndroidDevice.<init>(ConnectedAndroidDevice.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.DevicePickerListModel.wrapConnectedDevices(DevicePickerListModel.java:46)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.DevicePickerListModel.reset(DevicePickerListModel.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker.updateModel(DevicePicker.java:290)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker.lambda$null$1(DevicePicker.java:193)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:778)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:455)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1665)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1607)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1622)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.ShowChooserTargetProvider.showPrompt(ShowChooserTargetProvider.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getDeployTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:475)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:294)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:158)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:55)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:118)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$300(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:67)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:509)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException PluginClassLoader[com.google.gct.testing, 1.0]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 64 more


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSchException
    at com.google.gct.testing.android.CloudDeviceNameRenderer.isApplicable(CloudDeviceNameRenderer.java:31)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.ConnectedAndroidDevice.getRendererExtension(ConnectedAndroidDevice.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.ConnectedAndroidDevice.<init>(ConnectedAndroidDevice.java:56)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.DevicePickerListModel.wrapConnectedDevices(DevicePickerListModel.java:46)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.DevicePickerListModel.reset(DevicePickerListModel.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker.updateModel(DevicePicker.java:290)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:778)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:455)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1665)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1607)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1622)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.ShowChooserTargetProvider.showPrompt(ShowChooserTargetProvider.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getDeployTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:475)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:294)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:158)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:55)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:118)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$300(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:67)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:509)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException PluginClassLoader[com.google.gct.testing, 1.0]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: Did you try Clean and build?

Comment: It's an IDE Internal Error. Not a project error. I think Clean and Build are only for Project errors, not IDE errors. Also, like I said, I don't use JSch in my project, so Clean and Build won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when testing app on the emulator.

I disabled all Firebase plugins from IDE and it worked.

Here are extra details about my development environment:

```
Android Studio 2.3
Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Firebase plugin versions:

```
Firebase App Indexing: 0.1
Firebase Services: 0.1
Firebase Testing: 0.1
```

Comment: I think just disabling Firebase Testing is enough.

Comment: It was meant as a comment to describe what I did.
Since I am not using Firebase in my app so I disabled all of them.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, as I said in my second edit, since that Stacktrace turned out to have something to do with Firebase Testing, I disabled it. Now Android Studio properly detects my device.

Comment: Could you please explain what steps you have done. I'm having the same issue

Comment: Actually I'm not using Firebase in my current project, but used it in my previous project. Does that effect the new project?!!!

Comment: Basically I just looked at the error report in the details tab [the Firebase Testing plugin was the cause], then I just choose Disable Plugin and Restart. I think. There might be some steps I'm missing.